# Too Much Memory Usage for Windows form Application

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, memory, sharepoint-2007

I Made an application to download a folder from a given sharepoint site, but its consuming memory above 600,000K once i click on Connect button, anyone can give suggestion to improve my code ?

I Tried to debug my form and problem is coming at method " private void MapWebs(SPWebCollection webList, TreeNode webparentNode)"    where its calling itself again and again to go through each single web and its sub web, however I checked in the start when i click on connect and it goes through code line

```
using (SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(tbSite.Text))
```

The memory usage goes from   20,000 K to 40,000 K   (approx)

In order to run this application you must have sharepoint installed on yur PC, an example of this type of app is on this link ,

[enter link description here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/10/27/sharepoint-api-download-upload-documents-tool.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    //Connects to Sharepoint site provided and populates Webs and Subwebs and subwebs....
    private void bConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //Getting current site
            using (SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(tbSite.Text))
            {
                //Opening TopLevel Web for Site given
                using (SPWeb TopLevelWeb = CurrentSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    //Clearing all the nodes in TreeWeb
                    TreeWeb.Nodes.Clear();
                    //Creating a root (First Node for webtree) which will be Top Level web's title
                    TreeNode rootWebNode = new TreeNode(TopLevelWeb.Title);
                    //Giving node a tag, which will be used later on in order to get value of node
                    rootWebNode.Tag = TopLevelWeb;
                    //Check if Top Level Web got any Sub webs if it does, it will create a new node for them
                    //Calls Map Webs to check for more sub webs + mapping them on webtree as nodes
                    foreach (SPWeb CurrentWeb in TopLevelWeb.Webs)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TreeNode webNode = new TreeNode(CurrentWeb.Title);
                            webNode.Tag = CurrentWeb;
                            MapWebs(CurrentWeb.Webs, webNode);
                            TreeWeb.Nodes.Add(webNode);
                        }
                        finally 
                        {
                            if (CurrentWeb != null)
                                CurrentWeb.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // Maps Webs and there sub webs on webtree
    private void MapWebs(SPWebCollection webList, TreeNode webparentNode)
    {
            for (var i = 0; i < webList.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(webList[i].Name);

                using (SPWeb web = webList[i])
                {
                node.Tag = webList[i];
                    webparentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
                    if (webList[i].Webs.Count > 0)
                        MapWebs(webList[i].Webs, node);
                }
            }
            GC.Collect();
    }

    //when the form loads it clears the list and create new cloumns to be used
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bFolder.Enabled = false;
        bConnect.Enabled = false;
        lvFiles.GridLines = true;
        lvFiles.View = View.Details;
        lvFiles.Columns.Add("Name", lvFiles.Width/4, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvFiles.Columns.Add("Date Created", lvFiles.Width/3, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvFiles.Columns.Add("Size", lvFiles.Width / 5, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvFiles.Columns.Add("Time Last Modified", lvFiles.Width / 5, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        if (lvFiles.View == View.Details && lvFiles.Columns.Count > 0)
            this.Width = lvFiles.Columns.Count * (lvFiles.Width / 2);
        lvFiles.Columns[lvFiles.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2;
    }

    //creates directory for downloading folder
    private bool CreateDirectoryStructure(string baseFolder, string filepath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(baseFolder)) return false;

        var paths = filepath.Split('/');

        for (var i = 0; i < paths.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseFolder, paths[i]);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(baseFolder);
        }
        return true;
    }

    //opens an dialog box for selecting path where selected folder will be downloaded
    private void bBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.tbDirectory.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    //when a node is selected in webtree it checks for folders in it , + sub folders + folders......
    private void TreeWeb_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeFolder.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeNode currentNode = TreeWeb.SelectedNode;
        using (SPWeb oWeb = (SPWeb)currentNode.Tag)
        {
            foreach (SPList list in oWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (list is SPDocumentLibrary && !list.Hidden)
                {
                    TreeNode folderNode = new TreeNode(list.Title);
                    folderNode.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", list.Title, list.ItemCount);
                    folderNode.Tag = list.RootFolder;

                    foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Folders)
                    {
                        if (listItem.Folder != null)
                        {
                            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(listItem.Folder.Name);
                            node.Tag = listItem.Folder;
                            node.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", listItem.Folder.Name,
                                                 GetFilesCount(listItem.Folder));

                            MapFolders(listItem.Folder.SubFolders, node);
                            folderNode.Nodes.Add(node);
                        }
                    }

                    TreeFolder.Nodes.Add(folderNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Maps folder on foldertree
    private void MapFolders(SPFolderCollection folderList, TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < folderList.Count; i++)
        {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(folderList[i].Name);
                node.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", folderList[i].Name,
                                             GetFilesCount(folderList[i]));
                node.Tag = folderList[i];
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);

                if (folderList[i].SubFolders.Count > 0)
                    MapFolders(folderList[i].SubFolders, node);
        }
    }

    //Maps files in a folder to listview
    private void TreeFolder_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        lvFiles.Items.Clear();
        TreeNode currentNode = TreeFolder.SelectedNode;
        //if (currentNode != rotnode)
        //{
        double TotalSize = 0;
        SPFolder oFolder = (SPFolder)currentNode.Tag;
        foreach (SPFile oFile in oFolder.Files)
            {
                TotalSize += (oFile.Length)/1024/1024;

                ListViewItem LTI = new ListViewItem(oFile.Name.ToString());
                LTI.SubItems.Add(oFile.TimeCreated.ToString());
                LTI.SubItems.Add(oFile.Length.ToString());
                LTI.SubItems.Add(oFile.TimeLastModified.ToString());
                lvFiles.Items.Add(LTI);
            }
            label4.Text = TotalSize.ToString();
        //}
    }

    //download selected folder + validation
    private void bFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            TreeNode currentNode = TreeFolder.SelectedNode;
                SPFolder oFolder = (SPFolder)currentNode.Tag;
                foreach (SPFile file in oFolder.Files)
                {
                    if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url))
                    {
                        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, file.Url);
                        byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
                        System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                        fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                        fstream.Close();
                    }
                }
    }

    //calculates files in selected folder
    private int GetFilesCount(SPFolder folder)
    {
        int fileCount = folder.Files.Count;
        foreach (SPFolder subfolder in folder.SubFolders)
        {
            fileCount += GetFilesCount(subfolder);
        }
        return fileCount;
    }

    //validation
    private void tbSite_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbSite.Text != "")
            bConnect.Enabled = true;
        else
            bConnect.Enabled = false;
    }

    //validation
    private void tbDirectory_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbDirectory.Text != "" && TreeFolder.Nodes.Count != 0)
            bFolder.Enabled = true;
        else
            bFolder.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

Already checked with SP Dispose checker but it says this (at MapWebs method line "node.tag = weblist[i]... and if statement")

> Notes: Call to Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.get_Item and no variable to catch return value
>   More Information: http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_130

Comment: Try running the SharePoint Disposer Checker tool. It might highlight where things aren't being removed. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck. There's also a best practice guide which might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx#sharepointobjmodel__codingtechniques

Comment: You appear to be holding onto x-many `SPWeb` items by putting them into control tags. This class implements `IDisposable`. Perhaps you are simply trying to do too much?

Comment: @ KeyBoard , i already checked using SP Disposer Checkerand thats how i find out memory is leaking at method I mentioned above....

Comment: @ Adam Houldsworth , For a programmer there is nothing impossible , so I would like to hear positive responses please :) , thanks anyway

Comment: Try using some kind of memory profiler, I'll recommend http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ they have trial version

Comment: ^^ Already used that tool as well, its running that Loop i mentioned in method "MApweb" again and again and creating SPweb objects for it, but no wonder what i do , it doesn;t dispose created SPweb objects in that loop

Comment: Is there something else we should know but you didn't document in your question?  If your Winforms process is consuming 40 MB right now then don't bother, that is not unusual.  You only have a leak if you can get it to crash by doing something a million times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. You are disposing the `SPWeb` while iterating over the `SPWeb.Webs`, but you keep a reference on the `TreeNode.Tag`. When accessing the disposed `SPWeb` via the tag of the node SharePoint will "open" the web again. => Memory Leak
2. Since you are calling the `MapWebs` method recursive you have a lot of `SPWeb` objects opened simultaneously:

   ```
   Root -> open
     Child 1 -> open
       Child 1.1 -> open
           Child 1.1.1 -> open
       Child 1.2
       Child 1.3
       Child 1.4
   Child 2
   Child 3
   ```

Comment: thanks for your "comment" , I figured out that just few hours before and i got no clue how i can close the opened web,,,

what i did is commented out treeNode.tag  but it still taking too much memory, while gathering information, 

and i even commented out mapweb method , still going away far from normal

Comment: Have you tried to limit to elements opened? Are there a lot of webs/lists/folders/items? As I can see from your code these items all remain in memory. 10 webs with 10 lists with 10 folders with 10 items, depending on the memory footprint these items could consume a lot of memory....

Comment: Yes, there are alot of documents, but main problem is its not disposing objects, once it creates Child 1.1 ... Child 1.2 ....

only thing I can do is , change the logic or dispose objects